# Printing web fonts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, font-face

I am trying to print web pages that contain external CSS references and use web fonts (I mean @font-face attribute) but in print preview the web fonts disappear. Does anyone know a solution without using the web font locally?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like printing @font-face fonts is not yet implemented:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=468568

Comment: This bug is taking forever to fix

Comment: for context, this bug has existed since FF3. yes, 3. not 3.6. 3.

Answer (score 1):

Works as of Firefox 18! - Yippee!

Answer (score 0):

inlcude the file not only for screen but also for print

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />`

but include the css also for print

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="print" />`

in your case the href should then go to an external url

Comment: I'm already include my css in media print, but no response in print preview, The problem is in using @font face attribute, it is n supported in printing, I am trying to find some hack or Firefox plug-in or even a script to make my web font printable.

Comment: can't you separate your font attributes? font-family, font-size, ... in your css?

Comment: seems like a bug that wasn't solved yet for ff, all the other  browsers solved this problem. more info: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=en-US&comments_parentId=497167&forumId=1

Comment: yes you are right this is a ff bug, but I hope to find a hack to solve this problem temporarily

Comment: You can combine the two lines by using media="screen print" or media="all"

Comment: hey i tried both but none of it is working any other workaround that you can provide