# This method that i use for print doesn't use my font and color

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use below method for print (send each control that i want to print to it)
but this method doesn't print background color and font,... for example if background color of control that i sent to it is gray this method do it like when background color is white and doesn't use font that i use in the source control

```
public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl, string Script)
    {
        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        if (ctrl is WebControl)
        {
            Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage); ((WebControl)ctrl).Width = w;
        }
        Page pg = new Page();
        pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
        if (Script != string.Empty)
        {
            pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "PrintJavaScript", Script);
        }
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        pg.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        pg.DesignerInitialize();
        pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The background color is not changing to white because of your code. Its the browser that removes background colors and background images. For example, if you try to print this page, you will notice that the grey background of your code sample changes to white.

Users can control the printing of bg colors and images at browser level, for example, in IE, they would [follow these steps](http://www.febooti.com/support/faq/iezoom/print-web-page-background.html)

You can [setup a CSS print style sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/), which will give you more control on the print area.

Comment: from <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031272/printing-web-fonts-on-fire-fox">here</a>, it seems some browsers also do not support printing @font-face fonts. Not sure if there is a way around.

Comment: you mean it because of browser and not to print font until browser will update and implement print font on browser